# Chrome backgroundPage issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension and I designed it this way:

I have a:

- popup.html (browserAction popup);
- popup.js (included by popup.html);
- background.html (background script);
- background.js (included by background.js);

How should it work: the background page (and the related js) executes and creates an HTML table.

Once I click the browser action popup icon, I retrieve that table (through getBackgroundPage) from the background page DOM and I append it in the popup.html.

What happens: the first time I click the button anything works absolutely fine.

The second time, the popup.html doesn't display the table anymore (no table is appendend): so, I found background.html still exists BUT it has no more tables inside.

What happens to backgroundPage?

Relevant code:

```
// reference to the background page window
    var w = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    console.log(w);

    // the background page week table
    var newWeek = w.document.getElementById("week");

    console.log(newWeek);

    // the popup week table
    var oldWeek = document.getElementById("week");

    // replace popup table with background table (first time it works, second time newWeek is null)
    oldWeek.parentNode.replaceChild(newWeek,oldWeek);
```

Comment: Probably your code in popup.js is destroying the table. Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: I edit the post as soon as possible, but there's no code destroying the background table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively ***moving*** the table from the background page DOM tree to the popup DOM tree. When the popup is closed, the table is lost. You can try adding [`.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) so you get a copy of the table instead:

```
var newWeek = w.document.getElementById("week").cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: I can't believe it: I thought I was copying, not moving! Thank you very much!  :-)